# jdbRealm and BASIC http: Password login succeeded, webpage displays 403

Tags: java, basic-authentication, jdb

I've created a simple maven web project and try to secure it with BASIC authentication and jdbRealm.

On my glassfish 4.0 server i've created a realm and enabled 'Default Principal To Role Mapping'. Security logging level is set to finest.

my web.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>UserConstraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>ApiResource</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
            <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>jdbc-realm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

The realms seems to work. When i run the project, an authentication screen pops up and the login succeeded:

Glassfish output:

```
    Fine:   [Web-Security] Setting Policy Context ID: old = null ctxID = security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "" "GET")
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
Fine:   [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : null
Fine:   [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Finest:   JACC Policy Provider: PolicyWrapper.implies, context (security/security)- result was(false) permission (("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET"))
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Finest:   Processing login with credentials of type: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.PasswordCredential
Fine:   Logging in user [joost] into realm: jdbc-realm using JAAS module: jdbcRealm
Fine:   Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule
Finest:   JDBC login succeeded for: joost groups:[users]
Fine:   JAAS login complete.
Fine:   JAAS authentication committed.
Fine:   Password login succeeded for : joost
Fine:   Set security context as user: joost
Fine:   [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Generating a protection domain for Permission check.
Fine:   [Web-Security] Checking with Principal : joost
Fine:   [Web-Security] Checking with Principal : users
Fine:   [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : joost, users
Fine:   [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Finest:   JACC Policy Provider: PolicyWrapper.implies, context (security/security)- result was(false) permission (("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET"))
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Fine:   [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission" "" "GET")
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasUserDataPermission isGranted: true
Fine:   [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : null
Fine:   [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Finest:   JACC Policy Provider: PolicyWrapper.implies, context (security/security)- result was(false) permission (("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET"))
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Finest:   Processing login with credentials of type: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.PasswordCredential
Fine:   Logging in user [joost] into realm: jdbc-realm using JAAS module: jdbcRealm
Fine:   Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.JDBCLoginModule
Finest:   JDBC login succeeded for: joost groups:[users]
Fine:   JAAS login complete.
Fine:   JAAS authentication committed.
Fine:   Password login succeeded for : joost
Fine:   Set security context as user: joost
Fine:   [Web-Security] Policy Context ID was: security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Codesource with Web URL: file:/security/security
Fine:   [Web-Security] Checking Web Permission with Principals : joost, users
Fine:   [Web-Security] Web Permission = ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Finest:   JACC Policy Provider: PolicyWrapper.implies, context (security/security)- result was(false) permission (("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET"))
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: false
Fine:   [Web-Security] hasResource perm: ("javax.security.jacc.WebResourcePermission" "/index.html" "GET")
Fine:   FileRealm : file=C:\Users\Joost\School\S6\SOP\development_server\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\admin-keyfile
Fine:   FileRealm : jaas-context=ignore
Fine:   Login module initialized: class com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.FileLoginModule
Fine:   File login succeeded for: admin
Fine:   JAAS login complete.
Fine:   JAAS authentication committed.
```

However the page displays HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden.
I've no clue. I also tried this with custom principal role mappings but it didn't work neither.